# How to let objects move in different patterns

Tags: python, pygame

For my code, I would like the chickens (enemies) to move 4 different ways:

vertical, horizontal, diagonal and following the player (pig).

Each chicken should have its own movement and move independently. Only two chickens can go in diagonal.

I have only programmed their vertical and horizontal movements but there is a problem with them; sometimes, they all move horizontally, sometimes, vertically. Sometimes they don't move at all.

Here is my code:

```
def game_loop():

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0
    foodCounter = 0
    Score = 0           
    list =         ["Vertical","Vertical","Horizontal","Horizontal","Follow","Diagonal1","Diagonal2"]
    baddies = []
    item = 0

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    foodx = random.randrange(48, display_width - 48)
    foody = random.randrange(54, display_height - 54)

    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -8
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 8
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -8
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 8

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0

        if x > 705:
            x_change = 0
            x = 705
        if x < -10:
            x_change = 0
            x = -10
        if y < -15:
            y_change = 0
            y = -15
        if y > 505:
            y_change = 0
            y = 505

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(background,(-50,-50))

        food = pygame.Rect(foodx, foody,48 , 54)

        if foodCounter == 0:
            gameDisplay.blit(foodImage, food)

        player = pygame.Rect(x, y,108,105)

        if player.colliderect(food):
            foodCounter += -1
            Score += 1
            foodx = random.randrange(48, display_width - 48)
            foody = random.randrange(54, display_height - 54)
            foodCounter += 1

            item = random.randint(1, len(list))
            print(item)

            if item == 1 or item == 2:
                newchicken = {'rect':pygame.Rect(random.randint(0,display_width-45),0,45,63),
                          'surface':pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage,(45,63)),
                          'vertical': "vertical",
                          'down': "down"
                          }
                item = 0
                baddies.append(newchicken)

            if item == 3 or item == 4:
                newchicken = {'rect':pygame.Rect(0,random.randint(0,display_height-45),45,63),
                          'surface': pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage, (45,63)),
                          'horizontal': "horizontal",
                          'right': "right"
                          }
                item = 0
                baddies.append(newchicken)

            if item == 6:
                newchicken = {'rect':pygame.Rect(200,0,45,63),
                          'surface':pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage,(45,63)),
                          'diagonal1': "diagonal1"
                          }
                if "Diagonal1" in list:
                    list.remove("Diagonal1")

                item = 0
                baddies.append(newchicken)

            if len(list) == 7:
                if item == 7:
                    newchicken = {'rect':pygame.Rect(100,600,45,63),
                              'surface':pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage,(45,63)),
                              'diagonal2': "diagonal2"
                          }
                    if "Diagonal2" in list:
                        list.remove("Diagonal2")

                    item = 0
                    baddies.append(newchicken)
            if len(list) == 6:
                if item == 6:
                    newchicken = {'rect':pygame.Rect(100,600,45,63),
                              'surface':pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage,(45,63)),
                              'diagonal2': "diagonal2"
                          }
                    if "Diagonal2" in list:
                        list.remove("Diagonal2")

                    item = 0
                    baddies.append(newchicken)

        gameDisplay.blit(pigImage, player)

        for b in baddies:
            gameDisplay.blit(b['surface'],b['rect'])

        for b in baddies:
            if "vertical" in newchicken:
                if "down" in newchicken:
                    if not b['rect'].bottom >= 600:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(0, 2)
                    if b['rect'].bottom >= 600 :
                        del newchicken['down']
                        newchicken["up"] = "up"
                if "up" in newchicken:
                    if not b['rect'].top <= 0:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(0,-2)
                    if b['rect'].top <= 0:
                        del newchicken ['up']
                        newchicken["down"] = "down"

            if "horizontal" in newchicken:
                print ("horizontal")
                if "right" in newchicken:
                    if not b['rect'].right >= 800:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(2,0)
                    if b['rect'].right >= 800:
                        del newchicken['right']
                        newchicken['left'] = "left"
                if "left" in newchicken:
                    if not b['rect'].left <= 0:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(-2,0)
                    if b['rect'].left <= 0:
                        del newchicken ['left']
                        newchicken['right'] = "right"

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
```

Comment: Dumping 100s of lines of code hoping for us to debug for you without you having tried to narrow down your problem is a long shot... [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you always check for keys in `newchicken` when you iterate over `baddies`, while I guess you should check `b` instead.

But what you should do instead is to change your code in a way that seperates the different logical concerns of your game. Also, just use a class instead of a `dict` to group data and behaviour that belongs together.

---

Let's think a bit:

We have some kind of entity that basically consists of three things: an image, a position, and a behavior. You already know this, because you created these dicts:

```
newchicken = {'rect':pygame.Rect(100,600,45,63),
              'surface':pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage,(45,63)),
              'diagonal2': "diagonal2"
             }
```

Let's tweak this a bit and use a [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) (really, read the docs), which already has these things (more or less). Our class class could look like this (and don't tell me you don't want to use classes. That's stupid IMHO since you already use dozens of classes):

```
class Animal(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, pos, logic, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.surface.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.logic = logic
        self.direction = pg.Vector2((0, 0))

    def update(self):
        self.logic(self)
```

So, we have an `image` (which is just a plain rect so we have a working game at the end that everybody can copy/paste and run), a `rect` that stores the position, a mysterious `logic` argument that's a function (the "AI" of our animal) which will be called every tick, and a `direction`, which defines in which direction out animal will walk.

So, let's create the actual logic that will move out animals. We create three functions, one for vertical movement, one for horizontal movement, and one that will always walk towards the mouse cursor:

```
def move_vertical(animal):
    if animal.direction.length() == 0:
        animal.direction = pg.Vector2(5, 0)

    animal.rect.move_ip(*animal.direction)
    if not screen_rect.contains(animal.rect):
        animal.direction *= -1
        animal.rect.move_ip(animal.direction)

def move_horizontal(animal):
    if animal.direction.length() == 0:
        animal.direction = pg.Vector2(0, 5)

    animal.rect.move_ip(*animal.direction)
    if not screen_rect.contains(animal.rect):
        animal.direction *= -1
        animal.rect.move_ip(animal.direction)

def move_to_mouse(animal):
    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    v = pg.Vector2(pos) - pg.Vector2(animal.rect.center)
    if v.length() > 0:
        v.normalize_ip()
    v *= 5
    animal.rect.move_ip(*v)
```

If we now want to create an `Animal`, we simply pass one of those functions to the constructor. No need for massive if/else blocks in your main loop (note how clean and simple it is in the end).

---

So, here's our final example. Note how we create four animals: two that move vertically, one that moves horizontally, and one that follows the mouse.

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
clock = pg.time.Clock()
running = True
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

def move_vertical(animal):
    if animal.direction.length() == 0:
        animal.direction = pg.Vector2(5, 0)

    animal.rect.move_ip(*animal.direction)
    if not screen_rect.contains(animal.rect):
        animal.direction *= -1
        animal.rect.move_ip(animal.direction)

def move_horizontal(animal):
    if animal.direction.length() == 0:
        animal.direction = pg.Vector2(0, 5)

    animal.rect.move_ip(*animal.direction)
    if not screen_rect.contains(animal.rect):
        animal.direction *= -1
        animal.rect.move_ip(animal.direction)

def move_to_mouse(animal):
    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    v = pg.Vector2(pos) - pg.Vector2(animal.rect.center)
    if v.length() > 0:
        v.normalize_ip()
    v *= 5
    animal.rect.move_ip(*v)

class Animal(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, pos, logic, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.surface.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.logic = logic
        self.direction = pg.Vector2((0, 0))

    def update(self):
        self.logic(self)

sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
Animal(pg.color.Color('yellow'), ( 10,  10), move_vertical,   sprites)
Animal(pg.color.Color('red'),    (200, 400), move_vertical,   sprites)
Animal(pg.color.Color('orange'), (500, 100), move_horizontal, sprites)
Animal(pg.color.Color('brown'),  (100, 200), move_to_mouse,   sprites)

while running:

    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False

    sprites.update()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    sprites.draw(screen)
    pg.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

---

[image]